# What Are the Advantages Of a Strict 2 Column Layout Vs 12 With Elements Spanning Multiple Columns?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid-layout

Websites like the [Responsive Grid System](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/) allow you to generate the CSS code for anywhere from 2 to 12 columns in a row.

My question is this: If you can make an element span multiple columns (see their sample layouts), why would you ever choose to only allow two columns over 12 (with elements spanning multiple columns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only reason for choosing 2 columns over 12 is if you know you are never going to need more than 2  columns (which is a hard thing to know for sure).

And also, if you want to keep your code very simple.

I would stick with 12 so that you have the most options, and the easiest time, if you want to change things in the future.